# PHP Execute with > - Close

Tags: php, exec, proc-open

i try to make this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "<HTML><BODY>";
exec("echo Hallo > /tmp/testtt.txt", $output, $retval);
echo "Rückgabe mit Status $retval und Ausgabe:\n<br/>";
foreach($output as &$s){
       echo $s."<br/>";
}
echo "</BODY></HTML>";
?>
```

i already tried system, passthru, exec, popen
but, it never creates /tmp/testtt.txt
Rights of /tmp:

```
drwxrwxrwt  10 root root 220K Mai  3 10:28 tmp
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: How did you check /tmp/testtt.txt ? Did you try to chmod after exec?

Comment: ls /tmp/  --> no file there. i got Root acces to the webserver

Comment: Just to add, Your $output will not contain anything useful as there is no output from the exec command.

Comment: How about exec("echo Hallo > /tmp/testtt.txt ; chmod 777 /tmp/testtt.txt", $output, $retval);

Comment: Its a case of it "works for me" but while I have my /tmp owner/group as root root, I could still create the file with my user setting it to owner/group for the file. I have added myself to the sudo group. I'll need to try a virgin system.

Comment: Nope, it does nothing. i already added www-data to the sudoers. I can login with www-data to a other account. but i can not do touch or >

Comment: i found it. 'df -H: ' --> '/dev/sdb7       853G     80M  810G    1% /tmp' if i create a new folder /ttt and write the files there it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
exec('sh -c "echo Hallo > /tmp/testtt.txt"', $output, $retval);
```

Comment: The same. returncode 0 and the shell runs, but it cant create the file

Comment: Are you sure the file is not created. If you cd into your systems tmp folder using  cd /tmp is it in that folder? Or use ls /tmp

Comment: yes, i'm rot at the system. the file don't exists.  if i create the file and make chmod 777, it don't write into it.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the Sticky bit. /tmp/ has a Sticky bit - so there is a Problem with the PHP exec...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).